# How to stop iTunes on my PC to upload random picture on my iTunes iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music, itunes-match, pc

I download a lot of music from my PC iTunes to my iPhone iTunes. On the PC you have the option to choose the "Artwork" of each song you have on there, which I always personally choose, to fit with the song and/or artist you know, but once I drag them to my iPhone, on my iPhone in iTunes the songs are there, but with random pictures that I used in the past.

How do I change that to make sure the pictures I chose on my laptop, stay while going on my iPhone?

Answer (score -4):

If iTunes on your PC is uploading random pictures to your iPhone, there are a few things you can try to stop this:

Turn off automatic syncing: Open iTunes on your PC and connect your iPhone. Click on the iPhone icon in the upper left corner of the iTunes window, then go to the "Summary" tab. Under the "Options" section, uncheck the box next to "Automatically sync when this iPhone is connected." This will prevent iTunes from syncing any content to your iPhone automatically.

Manage sync settings: If you want to continue syncing some content, you can manage the sync settings for your iPhone in iTunes. Under the "Summary" tab for your iPhone, scroll down to the "Options" section and choose "Sync only checked songs and videos" or "Manually manage music and videos." This will allow you to select which content you want to sync to your iPhone.
Check iTunes settings: Open iTunes on your PC and go to "Preferences." Under the "Devices" tab, check the box next to "Prevent iPods, iPhones, and iPads from syncing automatically." This will prevent iTunes from syncing any content to your iPhone automatically.

Check iCloud settings: If you have iCloud Photo Library turned on, your iPhone may be uploading photos to iCloud, which can then sync to your other devices, including your PC. Open the Settings app on your iPhone, go to "Photos," and check the settings for iCloud Photo Library. You can turn it off or adjust the settings to prevent it from syncing automatically.

If none of these steps work, you may need to contact Apple support for further assistance.

Comment: The danger of copy/pasting answers from somewhere else is that they might answer the wrong question. Please reread the question to understand that it‘s not about photos, and that disabling sync most likely isn‘t an option.

Comment: It's rather a shame to revert an edit that actually *improves* the presentation of your post.

Comment: It's probably better for a clear understanding or your answer to leave the formatting as @agarza suggested.